# how to get a whole key of a dictionary with any single key of multiple key

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello i have a key value pairs in json , where i need to map a group of similar values to one value like many to one function

for example

**a-f** :***1***     **g-k**: ***2***   **L-p**:***3***

Here comes the dataframe with map

```
df['A'].map(lambda x: {'A':1,'B':1.....,'g':2....,'z':5}.get(x))
```

as the dictionary becomes big i used tuple for keys

```
df['A'].map(lambda x: {('a','b','c','d','e','f'):1,............,(v,w,x,y,z):6}.get(x))
```

now `if df['A'] == b it needed to be mapped to 1,`

same `if  df['A'] == e it should be mapped to 1  but the key for 1 is tuple(a,b,c,d,e,f)`

can any one tell me how to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

For readability, i suggest passing a function to map() instead of lambda function. I personally prefer string over tuple for simplicity, but using tuple works as well.

```
idx = {'abc':1,'defg':2,'hij':3}

def indexing(x):
    for k in idx.keys():
        if x in k:
            return idx[k]
    return 0

df['A'].map(indexing)
```

If you really want to use lambda function, you can try the following, but it gives less flexibility and less readability:

```
idx = {'abc':1,'defg':2,'hij':3}
df['A'].map(lambda x : sum([idx[k] if x in k else 0 for k in idx.keys()]))
```